# Pygame Mouse Drag Collisions

Tags: python, pygame, collision-detection, collision, maze

I'm pretty new to coding and pygame, and I am trying to make a simple maze game where you drag your character through the maze without hitting the sides (A bit like that board game 'Operation').

Most of it is working but I don't know the command to make it stop moving when it hits the walls of the maze. I have figured out how to make it look for a collision:

```
if player.colliderect(mazewall):
         ??????
```

but I'm not sure how to make 'player' not go through 'mazewall'. I am looking for something that works like this:

```
if player.bottom >= 390:
   player.bottom = 390
```

So you can mouse drag the player as much as you want and still not be able to pull it over or under the maze wall.
here is my full code so far:

```
#Import stuff
import pygame as pg
from pygame import Surface
import time
#Initialize
pg.init()

#Some colours
black = (0,0,0)
white = (255,255,255)
red = (255,0,0)
blue = (0,0,255)
green = (0, 255, 0)
walls = (146, 200, 203)
background = (253, 208, 236)

#Make the size of the panel
screen_width = 700
screen_height = 430
screen = pg.display.set_mode([screen_width, screen_height])
pg.display.set_caption("Runner")

#x, y, How big)
player = pg.rect.Rect(50, 350, 17, 17)
player_dragging = False

#Make the maze
mazewall = pg.rect.Rect(20, 390, 200, 20)

Run = True
while Run:
    for event in pg.event.get():
        #If the player clicks the close button
        if event.type == pg.QUIT:
            Run = False
        elif event.type == pg.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pg.K_ESCAPE:
                Run = False        
        #All the player dragging stuff
        elif event.type == pg.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            if event.button == 1:            
                if player.collidepoint(event.pos):
                    player_dragging = True
                    mouse_x, mouse_y = event.pos
                    offset_x = player.x - mouse_x
                    offset_y = player.y - mouse_y                  
        elif event.type == pg.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
            if event.button == 1:            
                player_dragging = False       
        elif event.type == pg.MOUSEMOTION:
            if player_dragging:
                mouse_x, mouse_y = event.pos
                player.x = mouse_x + offset_x
                player.y = mouse_y + offset_y


    #This is the bit I'm not sure about, I want it to work like this (Run the program)
    if player.bottom >= 390:
        player.bottom = 390
    #But with this instead

    #player.colliderect(mazewall)

    #Set the background
    screen.fill(background)

    #Draw the player
    pg.draw.rect(screen, black, player)
    #Draw the maze
    pg.draw.rect(screen, walls, mazewall)

    pg.display.flip()


pg.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add `player.colliderect(mazewall)`. In this way, if player collides with mazewall, colliderect function will be return True.

```py
    if player.bottom >= 390 and player.colliderect(mazewall):
        player.bottom = 390
```